# Limit of rational function solving

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, rational-functions

I have to solve limit of rational function, but it turns out I do mistake somewhere. Where I do wrong? Does my calculations correct?

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{x^3-2x-1}{x^5-2x-1}$$
Step 1: 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^5\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x^4}-\frac{1}{x^5}\right)}{x^5\left(1-\frac{2}{x^4}-\frac{1}{x^5}\right)}$$
Step 2: 
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^5\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x^4}-\frac{1}{x^5}\right)}{x^5\left(1-\frac{2}{x^4}-\frac{1}{x^5}\right)} = \frac{0-0-0}{1-0-0}=\frac{0}{1}=0$$

Comment: So $1=1*\infty$? I never knew that!

Comment: I cannot follow your every single step!!

Comment: Please check edited answer. Is that correct?

Comment: What's happening in the denominator?  It looks like your $x^3$ became $x^5$.  $x^5(1-\frac{2}{x^4}-\frac{1}{x^5})=x^5-2x-1$ which does not match the original denominator.

Comment: Should it remain $x^3$?

Comment: firstly write your question right then you will consider where you are making mistake

Comment: Your numerator and denominator of the original question are the same.  Therefore, the limit is $1$.

Comment: @NoorAslam What is not right?

Comment: The editing answer is exactly correct

Comment: Sorry for miss spelling. Do all agree now it is correct?

Comment: Actually, the last line (step 2) shouldn't have the limit in it any more because  you're substituting for $x$ at that point.

Comment: The answer as it stands now certainly isn't correct, the numerator in step 1 has two incorrect terms, namely $-2/x^2$ and $-1/x^3$

Comment: This method only works if the degree of the numerator and the denominator coincide.

Comment: @NoorAslam or Michael Burr to answer that question is correct now. Please add it as answer.

Comment: NoorAslam or Michael Burr to answer that question is correct now. Please add it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post edit answer is correct. However, it can be obtained with little (or practically no) calculations at all by using the properties of end behaviour of polynomials. 
The end behaviour of a polynomial function can be defined, informally, as the behaviour of the function's graph as it approaches $\pm \infty$.

For polynomial functions, the degree and the leading coefficient determine the end behaviour of the function. That means, as $x$ tends to infinity it is enough to analyse the leading term and coefficient to have an idea of what the graph will look like.

Limits are, on one hand, asking about the end behaviour. In your case, you have two polynomial functions that make up a rational function. Therefore we can combine the property of end behaviour of polynomials and the quotient rule of limits, $${\lim\limits_{x \to a} \frac{{f\left( x \right)}}{{g\left( x \right)}} }={ \frac{{\lim\limits_{x \to a} f\left( x \right)}}{{\lim\limits_{x \to a} g\left( x \right)}},\;\;\;}\kern-0.3pt 
{\text{if}\;\;\lim\limits_{x \to a} g\left( x \right) \ne 0}$$ to quickly get the answer by considering $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^3}{x^5} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x^2} = \frac{1}{\infty} = 0$$ Of course, all this can be done in the head in just a matter of seconds.

**To Sum It Up**

Suppose you are given two rational functions $$f(x)=a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0} $$and $$g(x)=b_{m}x^{m}+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_{1}x+b_{0}.$$
Then the value of $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ can be determined as follows:

$\bullet$ If $n>m$  and the sign of $a_n$ is the same as that of $b_m$ (i.e. $\frac{a_{n}}{b_{m}}$ is positive) then the limit is $\infty$

$\bullet$ If $n>m$  and the sign of $a_n$ is different from that of $b_m$, (i.e. $\frac{a_{n}}{b_{m}}$ is negative) then the limit is $-\infty$

$\bullet$ If $n<m$ then the limit is $0$.

$\bullet$ If $n=m$ then the limit is the value of $\frac{a_{n}}{b_{m}}$.

**Note that this method is only for limits to infinity**